# Planning to get rid of windows on an SSD I intend to use as a portable ubuntu drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, external-hdd

I've been dual-booting for the last year and I think I'm finally ready to go all in, my plan is to simply delete all ntfs partitions on my drive and leave the rest, I'll maybe leave a clean 50-100gib ntfs partition just in case I need it. Is this plan okay or what else should I do? Just wanna make sure I don't screw my ubuntu install.

Gparted:
[Here's what I have, I made the non-ntfs partitions a year and a half ago following a tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mINKM.png)

I just want to get rid of the windows installation and the boot manager (all of the important files have already been copied).

Edit: Just deleting all NTFS partitions worked like a charm, after that I just downloaded GRUB customizer to errase the whole Microsoft Boot Manager thing from there and now I have a portable installation that I can use wherever I want, I tried it with 2 very different (CPU, GPU and motherboard wise) machines and it worked first try just after placing the appropiate boot device as main on the BIOS, I'll try to use it on an even newer and different machine. If it all works and I don't face any problems in the next week I'll just post my own answer.

Comment: Hello. Do you intend to move this drive with the installed Ubuntu system from computer to computer?

Comment: @David yup, that's the intention

Comment: Generally this does not work well. As you move from machine to machine you will run into different video cards and other hardware. The video card will in most cases just give you a blank screen if the right driver is not loaded. So the best thing I can say is Good Luck!

Comment: If you want to move the disk to another computer, I would backup everything needed. Then wipe the disk, do a clean install and partition it as needed.

Comment: @David I should update the question, I got anxious and decided to do it last night only 20 minutes after asking the question, it works fine! I'm using a usb 3.0 to sata 3 so I'm pretty sure I'm not facing much bottleneck, works ok at first boot on my main pc which has an Nvidia card and AMD cpu, I tried it with an old laptop I have lying around which has an intel CPU and iGPU, I'll later try it on my work laptop which has an AMD APU. About the files everything important has already been backed up since yesterday, I'll keep ya posted thanks

Comment: @HomerSimpson Everything is backed up, thanks

Comment: Did you extend your Ubuntu partition in the end, or did you judt leave it as is?

Comment: @JoepieEs for some reason it wouldn't let me modify the size of the partition, so in the end I got a 240gib installation with a 200gib ntfs partition, thanks for asking

Answer (score 0):

What I would do first is make a USB-stick from which you could install Windows. Or keep the recovery-partition. Just to be sure. If you ever need to reinstall it, you can. Be sure you copy/save the key.
Then you can delete the NTFS partitions sda3 and 4. You can also delete sda2, the MRP. Some background information: The Microsoft Reserved Partition is essential if you want to use BitLocker drive encryption, which can't function otherwise. Important boot files are also stored here by default, although you could store them on the main Windows partition if you preferred. Source Dr. Google.
So now you have around 204 GB of unallocated space to the left of your Ubuntu partition. You cannot add space to this partition yet, as it is on the left of it. So you need to move sda5 to the left, so the free space is on the right side of it. This may take a while! Make sure you have backup!
Now you can enlarge sda5. If you want to leave space for Windows leave 100 GB (it needs that much) to make a NTFS partition.
Then you can use `sudo update-grub` to get rid of the windows entry in the EFI-partition.

Comment: What is this. It is the biggest mess of I do not know what I have ever seen. All these make and delete partitions. The OP asked a fairly simple but impractical question.

Comment: @ David Getting rid of Windows and extending his partition. If you know a better way, provide an answer.

Comment: That statement is good. The answer is not.

Comment: @David Seems to me you don't like the answers of JoepieEs. Not the first time you downvote his answer, although the answer(s) have a good base. But you provide no answers.

Comment: @JoepieEs Just deleting all ntfs partitions and then using GRUB customizer appears to have worked, thanks